# Grabbing json object data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to create an AJAX form that shows an error or success message when the field is filled in correctly. This is my code:

```
$('#name').keyup(function() {
    var name = $('#name').val();
    $.post('core/name_processing.php', { name: name }, function(data) {
        if (data.name === 'nodata') {
            $('#name_check').html('&nbsp;');
            $('.input_feedback').fadeOut('fast');
            $('.input_success').fadeOut('fast');
        } else if (data.name === 'success') {
            $('#name_check').html(data.name);
            $('.input_feedback').fadeOut('fast');
            $('.input_success').fadeIn('fast');
        } else {
            $('#name_check').html(data.name);
            $('.input_feedback').fadeIn('fast');
        }
    });
});
```

*'#name'* is the input field.

Here's the PHP:

```
<?php

$result = array();

if (isSet($_POST['name'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
        $result['name'] = 'nodata';
    } else {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
            $result['name'] = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
        } else if (strlen($name) > 10) {
            $result['name'] = 'success';
        } else {
            $result['name'] = strlen($name).' characters';
        }
    }
}

echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

The code worked just fine when I didn't use an array, but since I want to add more input fields I will need to return the data in an array. The problem seems to be that *data.name* is not a valid value, it does not grab the data as it should. How can I fix this?

*data* returns `{"name":"... characters"}`, `{"name":"nodata"}` and `{"name":"success"}` which seems to be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are lose function attribute and data type:

```
$.post('core/name_processing.php', { name: name }, function(data) {
    ....
}, 'json');
```

See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ for info.

Comment: That was a typo, sorry. It is in my code and with it, the problem persists.

Comment: Add 'json' as last $.post parameter